# Combining every two tuples within a list in Python

Tags: python

In a list of tuples, I'm trying to convert every consecutive pair to its sum.

E.g.,

```
[(t1, ), (t2, ), (t3, ), (t4, )] --> [(t1, t2) + (t3, t4)]
```

How can this be done?

---

Example:

```
 a = [(119, 'Bob', 1L, 1L), (116, 'Twilight Sparkle', 1L, 1L), (117, 'Fluttershy', 0L, 1L), (118, 'Applejack', 0L, 1L)]
```

Then the output should be:

```
 [(119, 'Bob', 1L, 1L, 116, 'Twilight Sparkle', 1L, 1L), (117, 'Fluttershy', 0L, 1L, 118, 'Applejack', 0L, 1L)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the list is:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Then using [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) (for Python2.7),

```
import itertools
```

you can use:

```
>> [aa + bb for (aa, bb) in itertools.izip(a[::2], a[1::2])]

[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be making a difference. My list is defined as result. So I tried this  [aa + bb for (aa, bb) in itertools.izip(result[::2], result[1::2])].

Was that the correct approach?

Comment: Yup, I suspect that your list is not of tuples at all. See edit to question.

Comment: @KishB87 See the change to your question. Placing parentheses around a Python object does *not* make it into a tuple: ``(2)`` is not a tuple, but ``(2, )`` is.

Comment: `result = [(119, 'Bob', 1L, 1L), (116, 'Twilight Sparkle', 1L, 1L), (117, 'Fluttershy', 0L, 1L), (118, 'Applejack', 0L, 1L)] `

This is my output right now. Are these not tuples?

Comment: `result = [(119, 'Bob', 1L, 1L, 116, 'Twilight Sparkle', 1L, 1L), (117, 'Fluttershy', 0L, 1L, 118, 'Applejack', 0L, 1L)] ` would be the desired output.

Comment: I updated the question to what I'm getting, and that's exactly what you're stating as the desired result. Are you sure you modified my expression from ``result`` to ``a`` correctly? It works by me. Try writing ``a = res`` and then my answer.